# webpack --watch gives this error ...no module named 'yargs'

Tags: javascript, webpack

below is the output that m getting, tried installing yargs and stuff but nothing is working :(

```
       `enter code here`module.js:471
            throw err;
            ^

        Error: Cannot find module 'yargs'
            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
            at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
            at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/webpack/bin/webpack.js:17:3)
            at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
            at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)


    My package.Json is:

    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.16.2",
        "elemental": "0.6.1",
        "flexboxgrid": "6.3.1",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "history": "4.5.1",
        "html-loader": "0.5.1",
        "leaflet": "1.0.3",
        "material-ui": "0.18.5",
        "material-ui-datetimepicker": "1.0.5",
        "material-ui-icons": "1.0.0-alpha.19",
        "react": "15.4.2",
        "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.6.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "0.31.1",
        "react-compose": "2.0.0",
        "react-dom": "15.4.2",
        "react-google-login": "3.0.4",
        "react-icons": "2.2.7",
        "react-leaflet": "1.2.2",
        "react-leaflet-heatmap-layer": "1.0.0",
        "react-leaflet-markercluster": "1.1.5",
        "react-redux": "5.0.6",
        "react-router": "3.0.2",
        "react-swipeable-views": "0.12.3",
        "react-tap-event-plugin": "2.0.1",
        "recharts": "0.20.8",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "4.4.2",
        "refire-app": "2.2.0",
        "yargs": "12.0.5"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "6.7.3",
        "babel-cli": "6.23.0",
        "babel-core": "6.23.1",
        "babel-loader": "6.3.2",
        "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.3.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.22.0",
        "babel-register": "6.23.0",
        "browser-sync": "2.18.8",
        "chai": "3.5.0",
        "chalk": "1.1.3",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
        "coveralls": "2.11.16",
        "cross-env": "3.1.4",
        "css-loader": "0.26.1",
        "enzyme": "2.7.1",
        "eslint": "3.15.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "6.10.0",
        "eslint-watch": "3.0.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
        "file-loader": "0.10.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
        "isparta": "4.0.0",
        "mocha": "3.2.0",
        "node-sass": "4.5.0",
        "npm-run-all": "4.0.1",
        "open": "0.0.5",
        "postcss-loader": "1.3.1",
        "prompt": "1.0.0",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.2",
        "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.4",
        "replace": "0.3.0",
        "rimraf": "2.5.4",
        "sass-loader": "6.0.1",
        "sinon": "1.17.7",
        "sinon-chai": "2.8.0",
        "style-loader": "0.13.1",
        "url-loader": "0.5.7",
        "webpack": "1.13.1",
        "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.12.2",
        "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
      },
```

I have been trying to develop an app lately and such issues r really demoralising. Please help.Also I have noticed similar errors pop-up every now and then when you to try to --watch,any specific startegy to expedite this troubleshooting?....from what I know we just need to keep googling till we find the correct solution.

Comment: You have `yargs` in your package.json so you should just need to run `npm install`. Have you tried this?

Comment: I managed to solve it on my own , it was because I was running the webpack--watch command in the wrong place.Anyways thanks for ur time and effort.:)